# How do I set share permissions in Windows 8

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, security

The code below works just fine when setting permissions on NT based machines, but something about windows 8 works differently. The code will create the share on Windows 8, but will not affect the "Share Permissions" page of the share properties.

To get to the properties page I'm talking about right click on a share and choose properties. From there select the "Sharing" tab and choose "Advanced Sharing." From here click the "Permissions" button. The groups will show "Everyone" and there will be options for "Full Control", "Change", and "Read" permissions towards the bottom of the dialog. These are the options I need to programmatically have selected. Like I said, the same code accomplishes this in Vista/Win 7 but not Windows 8.

Can someone please tell me how to do this in Windows 8? The answer can be in VB or C#, either is fine.

```
Private Function CreateWindowsShare(ByVal DirectoryToShare As String) As String

    Dim ManageClass As New ManagementClass("Win32_Share")
    Dim ReturnStatus As UInt32 = 0
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim CreatedShareName As String

    Do
        CreatedShareName = IIf(i = 1, "TestShare", "TestShare" & i)

        Dim inParams As ManagementBaseObject = ManageClass.GetMethodParameters("Create")
        inParams("Description") = ""
        inParams("Name") = CreatedShareName
        inParams("Path") = DirectoryToShare
        inParams("Type") = &H0

        Dim outParams As ManagementBaseObject = ManageClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, Nothing)

        ReturnStatus = Convert.ToUInt32(outParams.Properties("ReturnValue").Value)

        i += 1
    Loop While ReturnStatus = MethodStatus.DuplicateShare

    If ReturnStatus <> 0 Then
        Throw New Exception("Unable to create share.")
    End If

    ' For more info see:
    'http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/de213b61-dc7e-4f33-acdb-893aa96837fa/c-set-directory-sharing-permission-full-control-for-everyone-programmatically-in-windows-7-or?forum=windowssdk

    Dim ntAccount As New NTAccount("Everyone")

    Dim UserSID As SecurityIdentifier = ntAccount.Translate(GetType(SecurityIdentifier))
    Dim UtenteSIDArray(UserSID.BinaryLength) As Byte
    UserSID.GetBinaryForm(UtenteSIDArray, 0)

    Dim UserTrustee As New ManagementClass(New ManagementPath("Win32_Trustee"), Nothing)
    UserTrustee("Name") = "Everyone"
    UserTrustee("SID") = UtenteSIDArray

    Dim UserACE As New ManagementClass(New ManagementPath("Win32_Ace"), Nothing)
    UserACE("AccessMask") = 2302127  ' <-Full Access
    UserACE("AceFlags") = AceFlags.ObjectInherit Or AceFlags.ContainerInherit
    UserACE("AceType") = AceType.AccessAllowed
    UserACE("Trustee") = UserTrustee

    Dim UserSecurityDescriptor As New ManagementClass(New ManagementPath("Win32_SecurityDescriptor"), Nothing)
    UserSecurityDescriptor("ControlFlags") = 4 ' SE_DACL_PRESENT
    UserSecurityDescriptor("DACL") = New Object() {UserACE}

    Dim ShareClass As New ManagementClass("Win32_Share")
    Dim Share As New ManagementObject(ShareClass.Path.ToString & ".Name='" & CreatedShareName & "'")

    Share.InvokeMethod("SetShareInfo", New Object() {Int32.MaxValue, "", UserSecurityDescriptor})

    Return CreatedShareName
End Function

Public Enum MethodStatus
    Success = 0     'Success
    AccessDenied = 2    'Access denied
    UnknownFailure = 8  'Unknown failure
    InvalidName = 9     'Invalid name
    InvalidLevel = 10   'Invalid level
    InvalidParameter = 21   'Invalid parameter
    DuplicateShare = 22     'Duplicate share
    RedirectedPath = 23     'Redirected path
    UnknownDevice = 24  'Unknown device or directory
    NetNameNotFound = 25    'Net name not found
End Enum
```

Comment: Have you debugged this code on Win 8?  What part of the function isn't doing what it should?

Comment: The share gets created. Nothing throws and exception, it's just that the permissions are blank when it finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The issue is I messed up the access flag.

In my code its 2302127

It should read 2032127

The 0 and the 3 were flipped for some reason.